# Radar In Motion widget options for both macOS & Windows?

Tags: osx, macos, windows-8, weather

I was absolutely addicted to [Radar In Motion](http://dividedsoul.net/RadarInMotion/) for OS X.  It was by far one of the very handiest radar utilities (Animated Weather Maps) around.  Sadly the tool has been killed off now and I have been unable to find a replacement.

It offered a way to pull radars such as those [found in this video here](https://youtu.be/D13pthfl0bM?t=16) into a Dashboard widget for rapid reference and could be used to reliably determine storm/rain closeness and so forth visually. Everyone loved it passionately that I knew and used it very frequently.

For Windows, there was a [very old version](http://download.cnet.com/Radar-In-Motion/3000-12565_4-10719646.html) of it converted, but I cannot seem to make it work.

Do any such profoundly simple and elegant options exist for macOS and Windows now that are like Radar In Motion?